# How to make a post request in flask post method?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to wrote some code using flask let another server can post some data to it and then inside flask, when I receive the call from outside, I would like to make another post to another server.

Below is my code

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import json
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/sendData.json", methods=['POST'])
def receiveImageData():
    imageData = request.json

    # save data to son file
    with open(request.json['image_filename'].split('.')[0] + '.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(imageData, f, indent=4)

    # post some data to this url 
    r = requests.post('http://example.com/example.json', son = {'image_filename':'test.jpg', 'image_url': "http://images.come"})

    # return json data back for /sendData.json
    return jsonify({"status": "success"})
```

The problem is the last line {'status':'success'} will not return for sendData.json.

How can I fix it or there should be another way to make this happen?

Below is error log from flask

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Aug/2017 14:38:37] "POST /sendData.json HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
   File "/Users/bloomer/Documents/python/api_server/api.py", line 21, in receiveImageData
r = requests.post('http://example.com/example.json', son = {'image_filename':'test.jpg', 'image_url': "http://images.come"})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 112, in post
return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
```

Comment: Please check your Json.dumps function. Also I need to ask what are you doing to get the Json data by firing a GET request or POST since your method only allows POST request.

Comment: Json.dump function is fine, I just want to save data from  sendData.json post to a .json file and after that I would like to call a post api.

Comment: What is requests.post doing?

Comment: post some data to that url.

Comment: So actually the only thing not working is the last line, which just should send status "success" to the API, right?

Comment: yes, something like just stop on it and not return {status:success}

Comment: @Dreams please take a look at my edit

Answer (score 0):

Try it out with `return Response(), 200` at the end of `receiveImageData()`.

**EDIT:**

I researched a bit. Actually it should work. Try something like:

```
return jsonify({"success": True}), 202
```

What are the error messages you get? And is it the same server / API, where you post your data and status: success?

Comment: not working. Also, I would like to return some json data back.

Comment: Can you please add some comments to you snippet?

Comment: This is same server but different port , the another on is node.js (express).
There is no error msg and I just can not receive {status:success} after I call sendData.json. But I can receive it if I remove requests.post('http://example.com/example.json' on python side.

Comment: Well your error indicates, that host doesn't respon in expected manner - probably  the data it receives doesn't make any sense. You said if you remove 'example.com/example.json' then it works. So either your url is wrong (for example, https instead of http) or the problem is in using different ports for these two operations.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `jsonify({"status": "success"})` Use :

`return (Response(),200)`

Comment: not working. Also, I would like to return some json data back.